# How To Pass Multiple Files in Binary Format in Form Data in Azure Logic App HTTP

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

i am trying to pass two files in multipart form in the Azure Logic App in binary format. But the upload request gets reject. When i pass the same request in postman, the request is successful. PFB the details.

Postman Request:

[image]

Header:
[image]

Postman Curl Request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://abc/kofax/claims' \
--header 'x-abchk-msgid: 0214945a-509a-48af-9df2-281352806421' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXX' \
--form 'claimScanPDF=@"/C:/Users/ashutosh.bajpai/00000438.PDF"' \
--form 'claimScanJSON=@"/C:/Users/ashutosh.bajpai/kofax-op.json"'
```

Azure Logic App:
[image]

```
--testboundary
{
  "$content-type": "multipart/mixed",
  "$multipart": [
    {
      "body": @{concat(body('GETFILEPDF').$content)},
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name:claimScanPDF; filename=@{triggerBody()?['FileNamePDF']}"
      }
    },
    {
      "body": @{concat(body('GETFILEJSON').$content)},
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name:claimScanJSON; filename=@{triggerBody()?['FileNameJSON']}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
--testboundary--
```

i only get generic error message in response - The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.
Please help to understand what is the difference between postman and logic app request.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I got into the same issue.

Comment: @Pandiarajan used Function App later on.